# Return the record with the largest iteration

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table, called Document, that basically has the fields:

ID, Number, Revision, Iteration

There are some records that have the same Number and Revision, but multiple iterations (1, 2, 3, etc.).

I'm trying to return all rows where iteration is the highest, MAX(iteration), for any given Number and Revision combination.

Hopefully that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the table with max iteration:

```
    SELECT t1.* FROM DOCUMENT t1 INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT NUMBER, REVISION, MAX(ITERATION) 
    FROM DOCUMENT
    GROUP BY NUMBER, REVISION) t2 ON t1.NUMBER = t2.NUMBER AND
    AND t1.REVISION = t2.REVISION AND t1.ITERATION = t2.ITERATION
```

Comment: You need to add an alias to the `MAX(ITERATION)` column in your sub-query

Comment: Thanks a lot!!  I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around sub-queries with joins.  This was perfect!